# R segmented on time series object trying to make it work

Tags: r, breakpoints, piecewise

I've got a simple table (d_frame) with monthly Dates and Values 
dput does this:

> dput(d_frame)
>   structure(list(Dates = structure(c(1325376000, 1328054400, 1330560000, 
>   1333238400, 1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 1346457600, 
>   1349049600, 1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 
>   1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 
>   1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 
>   1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 
>   1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 
>   1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 
>   1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 
>   1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
>   1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
>   1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 
>   1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
>   ), tzone = "UTC"), Values = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00774754, 0.22403801, 
>   0, 5.12030095, 0.23120272, 0.99000874, 22.22207733, 0.333296, 
>   692.19566134, 7.76688971, 2.97430466, 134.36211377, 22.91894814, 
>   65.14574578, 135.81266758, 18.37095304, 185.25901758, 233.86535558, 
>   50.19910856, 67.54904705, 92.09374684, 236.3588002, 39.6182546, 
>   107.01412237, 45.46568388, 28.46083664, 147.03030045, 12.05623131, 
>   86.26622661, 86.78390353, 52.59616771, 135.24410876, 752.67471689, 
>   90.77072693, 318.08100321, 190.17687122, 32.45995024, 229.85208941, 
>   99.68676994, 78.23118358, 75.22676899, 244.54213373, 250.24590849, 
>   129.22758339, 220.46666166, 145.10114173, 76.27997413, 134.1304349, 
>   93.95382007, 171.43174451, 205.318684, 72.75873803, 905.44077088, 
>   65.68187302, 186.01373065, 22.39356267, 58.0947934, 345.76627723, 
>   49.2540693, 77.10619382, 73.55552926, 847.78421674, 43.39077872, 
>   49.83486911, 405.60316183, 18.25071976)), row.names = c(NA, -72L
>   ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

In R d_frame it looks like this:

[image]

Working with d_frame, I've made a timeseries out of it with:

```
d.ts <- ts(d_frame[2], start = c(2011, 12), frequency = 12)
```

It's has distinct trend but with huge random component, so I used TRR library to extract trend component out of d.ts:

```
dts_components <- decompose(d.ts)

dts_trend <- dts_components$trend
```

Then I make a linear model out of trend:

```
trend_lin.mod <- lm(dts_trend[,1] ~ time(dts_trend))
```

Now, as I see 3 stages on graph (I know they are there), I want to perform piecewise analysis with Segmented library.
I am trying to make Segmented model with break dates included or without them and get errors:

```
d.seg <- segmented(dts_trend, seg.Z = ~ time(dts_trend), psi = list(c('2014-07-01', '2016-10-01')))
```

which gives:

> Error in segmented.default(dts_trend, seg.Z = ~time(dts_trend), psi =
>   list(c("2014-07-01",  :    Variables in `seg.Z' and`psi' do not match

or I try one with no psi included:

```
d.seg <- segmented(dts_trend, seg.Z = ~ time(dts_trend))
```

which gives:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

All I want to make Segmented work on my timeseries dts_trend.
If you can help, I would really appreciate it, as I'm new to R and really got stuck.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of your data. Insert the data with dput. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)